# Combine Fields in MS Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have two fields, tblIT.Person_Name and tblEng.Full_Name. I want to create a new column that contains all of the names from the first table and adds them to the second column and places it all into one main column

```
Person_name
-------------
John Smith  |
-------------
Gary Porter |

Full_name
-------------
Gary Porter |
-------------
Nancy Becker|
```

I am looking for this:

```
People
-------------
Gary Porter |
-------------
Nancy Becker|
-------------
John Smith  |
```

It is not concatenating, which a lot of people have been telling me, it is simply joining the two tables.

Comment: What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: I am looking to have one full column of names. Basically appending the names from one column onto another, but still having them be distinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a UNION of the 2 tables.  This will weed out duplicate values.

```
SELECT Person_name AS People FROM tblIT
UNION
SELECT Full_Name FROM tblEng
```

You would use UNION ALL if you wanted all the rows from both tables, including the duplicates.  But it looks like you don't want duplicates.

The result set will not be editable.

If you want to store those in a column in another table, you can insert the results from the UNION query.  The UNION keyword may cause a syntax error with a simple INSERT statement, so include the UNION as a subquery in the INSERT.

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (People)
SELECT sub.People
FROM
    (
        SELECT Person_name AS People FROM tblIT
        UNION
        SELECT Full_Name FROM tblEng
    ) AS sub
```

Comment: I love this answer. But I keep getting an error when it hits the union. I am using the Insert Into and it is having trouble with it.

Comment: I didn't realize the UNION would cause an error with the INSERT I suggested.  Try the revised version.  I tested it with your data in Access 2007, and it works without error for me.

Answer (score 0):

use `UNION` (*without the ALL because it will allow duplicate*) to merge all the results.

```
SELECT col1 FROM Person_name
UNION
SELECT col1 FROM Full_name
```

It's combining the results, not joining the results :)